# Type underline in latex

Tags: underline

I was intending to type something like

`use_aesni = True` in latex.

Therefore, I type `$use_aesni = True$`. However, it becomes this.

[image]

Comment: `\textrm{use\_aensi}`  and `\mathrm{True}` (apart from the `_` don't use math italic for multi-letter words

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the underscore. `$use\_aesni = True$`

Comment: While this does answer the question, the result is still poor in terms of the letter kerning.